# When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, linked-list

I've always been one to simply use:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

I use the interface as the type name for *portability*, so that when I ask questions such as this, I can rework my code.

When should [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) be used over [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and vice-versa?

Comment: See also: [Array versus linked-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166884/array-versus-linked-list?rq=1)

Comment: Just see the quote from the author of LinkedList https://stackoverflow.com/a/42529652/2032701 and you'll get a practical sense of the issue.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has also discussed this extensively for C++ `std::vector` (like Java `ArrayList`) and `std::list` (like Java `LinkedList`).

Answer (score 3865, accepted):

**Summary** `ArrayList` with `ArrayDeque` are preferable in *many* more use-cases than `LinkedList`. If you're not sure — just start with `ArrayList`.

---

TLDR, in `ArrayList` accessing an element takes constant time [O(1)] and adding an element takes O(n) time [worst case]. In `LinkedList` inserting an element takes O(n) time and accessing also takes O(n) time but `LinkedList` uses more memory than `ArrayList`.

`LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are two different implementations of the `List` interface. `LinkedList` implements it with a doubly-linked list. `ArrayList` implements it with a dynamically re-sizing array.

As with standard linked list and array operations, the various methods will have different algorithmic runtimes.

For [`LinkedList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html)

- `get(int index)` is *O(n)* (with *n/4* steps on average), but *O(1)* when `index = 0` or `index = list.size() - 1` (in this case, you can also use `getFirst()` and `getLast()`). **One of the main benefits of** `LinkedList<E>`
- `add(int index, E element)` is *O(n)* (with *n/4* steps on average), but *O(1)* when `index = 0` or `index = list.size() - 1` (in this case, you can also use `addFirst()` and `addLast()`/`add()`). **One of the main benefits of** `LinkedList<E>`
- `remove(int index)` is *O(n)* (with *n/4* steps on average), but *O(1)* when `index = 0` or `index = list.size() - 1` (in this case, you can also use `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()`). **One of the main benefits of** `LinkedList<E>`
- `Iterator.remove()` is *O(1)*. **One of the main benefits of** `LinkedList<E>`
- `ListIterator.add(E element)` is *O(1)*. **One of the main benefits of** `LinkedList<E>`

<sup>Note: Many of the operations need *n/4* steps on average, *constant* number of steps in the best case (e.g. index = 0), and *n/2* steps in worst case (middle of list)</sup>

For [`ArrayList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)

- `get(int index)` is *O(1)*. **Main benefit of** `ArrayList<E>`
- `add(E element)` is *O(1)* amortized, but *O(n)* worst-case since the array must be resized and copied
- `add(int index, E element)` is *O(n)* (with *n/2* steps on average)
- `remove(int index)` is *O(n)* (with *n/2* steps on average)
- `Iterator.remove()` is *O(n)* (with *n/2* steps on average)
- `ListIterator.add(E element)` is *O(n)* (with *n/2* steps on average)

<sup>Note: Many of the operations need *n/2* steps on average, *constant* number of steps in the best case (end of list), *n* steps in the worst case (start of list)</sup>

`LinkedList<E>` allows for constant-time insertions or removals *using iterators*, but only sequential access of elements. In other words, you can walk the list forwards or backwards, but finding a position in the list takes time proportional to the size of the list. Javadoc says *"operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer"*, so those methods are *O(n)* (*n/4* steps) on average, though *O(1)* for `index = 0`.

`ArrayList<E>`, on the other hand, allow fast random read access, so you can grab any element in constant time. But adding or removing from anywhere but the end requires shifting all the latter elements over, either to make an opening or fill the gap. Also, if you add more elements than the capacity of the underlying array, a new array (1.5 times the size) is allocated, and the old array is copied to the new one, so adding to an `ArrayList` is *O(n)* in the worst case but constant on average.

So depending on the operations you intend to do, you should choose the implementations accordingly. Iterating over either kind of List is practically equally cheap. (Iterating over an `ArrayList` is technically faster, but unless you're doing something really performance-sensitive, you shouldn't worry about this -- they're both constants.)

The main benefits of using a `LinkedList` arise when you re-use existing iterators to insert and remove elements. These operations can then be done in *O(1)* by changing the list locally only. In an array list, the remainder of the array needs to be *moved* (i.e. copied). On the other side, seeking in a `LinkedList` means following the links in *O(n)* (*n/2* steps) for worst case, whereas in an `ArrayList` the desired position can be computed mathematically and accessed in *O(1)*.

Another benefit of using a `LinkedList` arises when you add or remove from the head of the list, since those operations are *O(1)*, while they are *O(n)* for `ArrayList`. Note that `ArrayDeque` may be a good alternative to `LinkedList` for adding and removing from the head, but it is not a `List`.

Also, if you have large lists, keep in mind that memory usage is also different. Each element of a `LinkedList` has more overhead since pointers to the next and previous elements are also stored. `ArrayLists` don't have this overhead. However, `ArrayLists` take up as much memory as is allocated for the capacity, regardless of whether elements have actually been added.

The default initial capacity of an `ArrayList` is pretty small (10 from Java 1.4 - 1.8). But since the underlying implementation is an array, the array must be resized if you add a lot of elements. To avoid the high cost of resizing when you know you're going to add a lot of elements, construct the `ArrayList` with a higher initial capacity.

If the data structures perspective is used to understand the two structures, a LinkedList is basically a sequential data structure which contains a head Node. The Node is a wrapper for two components : a value of type T [accepted through generics] and another reference to the Node linked to it. So, we can assert it is a recursive data structure (a Node contains another Node which has another Node and so on...). Addition of elements takes linear time in LinkedList as stated above.

An ArrayList is a growable array. It is just like a regular array. Under the hood, when an element is added, and the ArrayList is already full to capacity, it creates another array with a size which is greater than previous size. The elements are then copied from previous array to new one and the elements that are to be added are also placed at the specified indices.

Comment: One thing many people forget is that ArrayList is compact in memory which means that it's more cache friendly than LinkedList. LinkedList could be spread out all over RAM, while ArrayList is always snuggly packed together to take advantage of  spacial locality. This has important real world ramifications.

Comment: @AminM Only the object references are compact. The objects themselves can be scattered... Until we get value types.

Comment: @swpalmer certainly.
However, in a LinkedList just to FIND the item you're looking for you're touring your RAM layout. Whereas with the ArrayList you can scan through it with very few cache misses. 

Cache misses are a big deal for performance.

Comment: @AminM My point is that to find what you are looking for you likely still need to follow that reference and possibly suffer a cache miss.  Unless all you care about is reference identity.  I get that in the linked case you can suffer the cache miss just getting to the references themselves.  I'm just saying Java arrays suffer from cache misses in another way as well... until Valhalla.

Comment: @swpalmer my point is that its significantly less cache misses. In the extreme. Others have posted performance comparisons here. You can be sure that you'll get much worse performance with a LinkedList almost always.

Comment: Yes, this is crucial -- for most usecases ArrayList performs far better than LinkedList due to better cache locality.

Comment: @all - For LinkedList is it not 0{1) for adding the element into list?

Comment: No, because all the following elements need to be pushed downward in memory. When you add to the END of the array list it is O(1), unless the list needs to be resized.

Comment: @TodHarter I think Ajay is right, since the LinkedList class in Java is actually [implemented as a Doubly-linked list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: @Mahm00d You have to traverse the list to find the spot where you are inserting, so it is at least proportionate to the insertion point, O(N) where N is the index to insert at. This means it isn't NECESSARILY scaled to the size of the list, that is true. The way I said it is kind of poor.

Comment: @TodHarter You are right when we are 'inserting'. But with 'adding' the elements (to the end of the list), doubly-linked list will be O(1).

Comment: @Mahm00d Yeah, I thought I noted that, this is also true for ArrayList. Basically LinkedList's only claim to fame is that insert only requires rewriting 4 pointers, but ArrayList is forced to shift some number of elements, plus possibly resize the whole backing array. Thus the few edge cases where it outperforms an ArrayList.

Comment: @TodHarter inserting into a `LinkedList` requires more than rewriting 4 pointers. The insertion operation will always allocate a new node object, which has an object header (at least the size of two pointers), a previous and next pointer, and a reference to the actual element. Then, the previous and next pointers of the adjacent nodes have to be updated. So it’s in the order of magnitude of 7 words/pointers. So the amortized costs of adding to an `ArrayList` may involve multiple copy operations and still outperform `LinkedList`.

Comment: Bad summary. NEVER prioritize performance over readability and maintainability. The most used elements in lists are the first and last elements, so `LinkedList`'s `#getFirst` and `#getLast` are immensely more readable than `List#get` called with `0` and `#size() - 1`. So start with `LinkedList` and only change to `ArrayList` if performance is really crippled.

Comment: Try adding a million elements to a linked list and an array list and you will quickly learn that linked is orders of magnitude better for this.

Answer (score 697):

Thus far, nobody seems to have addressed the memory footprint of each of these lists besides the general consensus that a `LinkedList` is "lots more" than an `ArrayList` so I did some number crunching to demonstrate exactly how much both lists take up for N null references.

Since references are either 32 or 64 bits (even when null) on their relative systems, I have included 4 sets of data for 32 and 64 bit `LinkedLists` and `ArrayLists`.

**Note:** The sizes shown for the `ArrayList` lines are for *trimmed lists* - In practice, the capacity of the backing array in an `ArrayList` is generally larger than its current element count.

**Note 2:** *(thanks BeeOnRope)* As CompressedOops is default now from mid JDK6 and up, the values below for 64-bit machines will basically match their 32-bit counterparts, unless of course you specifically turn it off.

---

[image: Graph of LinkedList and ArrayList No. of Elements x Bytes]

---

The result clearly shows that `LinkedList` is a whole lot more than `ArrayList`, especially with a very high element count. If memory is a factor, steer clear of `LinkedLists`.

The formulas I used follow, let me know if I have done anything wrong and I will fix it up. 'b' is either 4 or 8 for 32 or 64 bit systems, and 'n' is the number of elements. Note the reason for the mods is because all objects in java will take up a multiple of 8 bytes space regardless of whether it is all used or not.

**ArrayList:**

`ArrayList object header + size integer + modCount integer + array reference + (array oject header + b * n) + MOD(array oject, 8) + MOD(ArrayList object, 8) == 8 + 4 + 4 + b + (12 + b * n) + MOD(12 + b * n, 8) + MOD(8 + 4 + 4 + b + (12 + b * n) + MOD(12 + b * n, 8), 8)`

**LinkedList:**

`LinkedList object header + size integer + modCount integer + reference to header + reference to footer + (node object overhead + reference to previous element + reference to next element + reference to element) * n) + MOD(node object, 8) * n + MOD(LinkedList object, 8) == 8 + 4 + 4 + 2 * b + (8 + 3 * b) * n + MOD(8 + 3 * b, 8) * n + MOD(8 + 4 + 4 + 2 * b + (8 + 3 * b) * n + MOD(8 + 3 * b, 8) * n, 8)`

Comment: The problem with your math is that your graph greatly exaggerates the impact.  You are modelling objects which each contain only an ```int```, so 4 or 8 bytes of data.  In the linked list, there are essentially 4 "words" of overhead.  Your graph thus gives the impression that linked lists use "five times" the storage of array lists.  This is wrong.  The overhead is 16 or 32 bytes per object, as an additive adjustment, not a scaling factor.

Comment: In addition, in many cases the object will not be an integer but a big object.  Say you're implementing undo in your app, so the object is the change that was made, which might be a lot of bytes.  So LinkedList is still more memory than ArrayList, but only negligibly more.

Answer (score 311):

`ArrayList` is what you want. `LinkedList` is almost always a (performance) bug.

Why `LinkedList` sucks:

- It uses lots of small memory objects, and therefore impacts performance across the process.
- Lots of small objects are bad for cache-locality.
- Any indexed operation requires a traversal, i.e. has O(n) performance. This is not obvious in the source code, leading to algorithms O(n) slower than if `ArrayList` was used.
- Getting good performance is tricky.
- Even when big-O performance is the same as `ArrayList`, it is probably going to be significantly slower anyway.
- It's jarring to see `LinkedList` in source because it is probably the wrong choice.

Comment: Try adding a million elements to a linked list and an array list and you will quickly learn that linked is orders of magnitude better for this.

Comment: @user207421 Ha, ha. I just tired it. `ArrayList` is over an order of magnitude faster (on my machine), and will have used less memory. (Fifth run: 2.6 ms vs 63 ms - that just a couple billionths of second per iteration for the array version.)

Answer (score 193):

```
Algorithm           ArrayList   LinkedList
seek front            O(1)         O(1)
seek back             O(1)         O(1)
seek to index         O(1)         O(N)
insert at front       O(N)         O(1)
insert at back        O(1)         O(1)
insert after an item  O(N)         O(1)
```

[Algorithms: Big-Oh Notation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180729155145/http://leepoint.net/algorithms/big-oh/bigoh.html) (archived)

ArrayLists are good for write-once-read-many or appenders, but bad at add/remove from the front or middle.

Comment: You can't compare big-O values directly without thinking about constant factors.  For small lists (and most lists are small), ArrayList's O(N) is faster than LinkedList's O(1).

Comment: I don't care about small lists performance, and neither does my computer *unless* it is used in a loop somehow.

Comment: LinkedList can't really insert in the middle in `O(1)`. It has to run through half the list to find the insertion point.

Comment: LinkedList: insert in middle O(1) - is WRONG! I found out that even insertion into 1/10th position of the LinkedList size is slower than inserting an element into 1/10th position of an ArrayList. And even worse: the end of collection. inserting into last positions (not the very last) of ArrayList is faster then into last positions (not the very last) of LinkedList

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840648/why-is-inserting-in-the-middle-of-a-linked-list-o1

Comment: @kachanov Inserting in a `LinkedList` *is* `O(1)` **if you have an iterator to the insert position**, i.e. `ListIterator.add` is supposedly `O(1)` for a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: right. "If you have an iterator to the insert position". But if you don't have it, inseting in a LinkedList is NOT O(1). As you can see the original post, it says: "insert in middle" it does not say "insert in middle where you have a position found by iterator"

Comment: Bad wording by the author. I'll edit his answer to clarify. Yes, seeking to the arithemetic average of the lists length will take `O(N)`.

Comment: I might would word it as "Insert after a node." You can insert after a given node whether you have an iterator or not. I still think insert in the middle means the same thing, and is clearer.

Comment: Nice answer. A small thing though : For `ArrayList` inserting at back is not always O(1). Maybe most of the times. But when it needs to reallocate the internal array a full copy will occur and a cost of O(n) will be incurred.

Comment: True.  This is still considered amortized O(1), ie http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/06A_Amortizing.html

Comment: @Anony-Mousse mind that manipulating a `List` via an iterator will invalidate all other potentially existing iterators of that list, so it is impossible to keep multiple iterators to interesting spots in a large list; you can keep at most one iterator for manipulations which has to be moved to the next location sequentially. This makes the scenario where you have an iterator pointing to the desired position, to make a manipulation in `O(1)` an entirely theoretical one. That’s not a deficiency of linked lists in general, it’s just that Java’s Collection API is not really designed for them.

Answer (score 160):

See 2021 update from author below the original answer.

---

**Original answer (2011)**

As someone who has been doing operational performance engineering on very large scale SOA web services for about a decade, I would prefer the behavior of LinkedList over ArrayList.  While the steady-state throughput of LinkedList is worse and therefore might lead to buying more hardware -- the behavior of ArrayList under pressure could lead to apps in a cluster expanding their arrays in near synchronicity and for large array sizes could lead to lack of responsiveness in the app and an outage, while under pressure, which is catastrophic behavior.

Similarly, you can get better throughput in an app from the default throughput tenured garbage collector, but once you get java apps with 10GB heaps you can wind up locking up the app for 25 seconds during a Full GCs which causes timeouts and failures in SOA apps and blows your SLAs if it occurs too often.  Even though the CMS collector takes more resources and does not achieve the same raw throughput, it is a much better choice because it has more predictable and smaller latency.

ArrayList is only a better choice for performance if all you mean by performance is throughput and you can ignore latency.  In my experience at my job I cannot ignore worst-case latency.

**Update (Aug 27, 2021 -- 10 years later)**

This answer (my most historically upvoted answer on SO as well) is very likely wrong (for reasons outlined in the comments below).  I'd like to add that ArrayList will optimize for sequential reading of memory and minimize cache-line and TLB misses, etc.  The copying overhead when the array grows past the bounds is likely inconsequential by comparison (and can be done by efficient CPU operations).  This answer is also probably getting worse over time given hardware trends.  The only situations where a LinkedList might make sense would be something highly contrived where you had thousands of Lists any one of which might grow to be GB-sized, but where no good guess could be made at allocation-time of the List and setting them all to GB-sized would blow up the heap.  And if you found some problem like that, then it really does call for reengineering whatever your solution is (and I don't like to lightly suggest reengineering old code because I myself maintain piles and piles of old code, but that'd be a very good case of where the original design has simply run out of runway and does need to be chucked).  I'll still leave my decades-old poor opinion up there for you to read though.  Simple, logical and pretty wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't another solution be managing the size of the list programmatically by using the ArrayList's ensureCapacity() method? My question is why are so many things being stored in a bunch of brittle data structures when they might better be stored in a caching or db mechanism? I had an interview the other day where they swore up and down about the evils of ArrayList, but I come here and I find that the complexity analysis is all-around better! GREAT POINT FOR DISCUSSION, THOUGH. THANKS!

Comment: *once you get java apps with 10GB heaps you can wind up locking up the app for 25 seconds during a Full GCs which causes timeouts* Actually with LinkedList you murder the garbage collector during full GCs, it has to iterate the overly large LinkedList with cache miss on each node.

Comment: @bestsss What he is saying that you will never trigger a full GC cycle with link lists; the list will grow and shrink in increments of one element and the CMS GC will run continually; no hiccups.

Comment: That's... a horrible solution.  you're basically reliant on the GC cleaning up for you, which is incredibly expensive, when you can just call ensureCapacity() on an arraylist instead...

Comment: @Andreas: when a list grows and shrinks in increments of one element, there is no problem with `ArrayList` at all, as it doesn’t even need additional memory for that. Considering the possibility that the `ArrayList` has to increase its capacity *once* during the entire life time of a web service as a reason to downgrade performance with a `LinkedList`, is quite strange, especially, if you consider the cost of the web service’s I/O in comparison. Expanding the capacity of an `ArrayList`, even with millions of elements, is rather unlikely to be noticed as latency.

Comment: @Holger An array list that increments over its capacity allocates a new list with 50% more room. For that increment you need 2.5 times the memory (and you likely need full gc cycle afterwards). I'm not concerned about day to day response time, I'm worried about running out of heap memory when a peak hour hits slightly harder than it hit yesterday and a couple big arraylists deciding they need room for 2.5 times their count for a second or two. One instance of that type of behavior during peak usage blows my sla for the whole month.

Comment: @Andreas: A `LinkedList` *always* allocates five times the memory than a plain array of references, so an `ArrayList` temporarily requiring 2.5 times still consumes far less memory, even while the memory is not reclaimed. Since large array allocation bypasses the Eden space, they don’t have any impact on GC behavior, unless there is really not enough memory, in which case, the `LinkedList` blew up much earlier…

Answer (score 137):

Joshua Bloch, the author of LinkedList:

> Does anyone actually use LinkedList?  I wrote it, and I never use it.

Link: https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248

I'm sorry for the answer not being as informative as the other answers, but I thought it would be the most self-explanatory if not revealing.

Answer (score 122):

Yeah, I know, this is an ancient question, but I'll throw in my two cents:

LinkedList is *almost always* the wrong choice, performance-wise.  There are some very specific algorithms where a LinkedList is called for, but those are very, very rare and the algorithm will usually specifically depend on LinkedList's ability to insert and delete elements in the middle of the list relatively quickly, once you've navigated there with a ListIterator.

There is one common use case in which LinkedList outperforms ArrayList: that of a queue.  However, if your goal is performance, instead of LinkedList you should also consider using an ArrayBlockingQueue (if you can determine an upper bound on your queue size ahead of time, and can afford to allocate all the memory up front), or this [CircularArrayList implementation](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue027.html).  (Yes, it's from 2001, so you'll need to generify it, but I got comparable performance ratios to what's quoted in the article just now in a recent JVM)

Comment: From Java 6 you can use `ArrayDeque`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Comment: `ArrayDeque` is slower than `LinkedList` unless all operations are at the same end. It's OK when used as a stack but it doesn't make a good queue.

Comment: Untrue - at least for Oracle's implementation in jdk1.7.0_60 and in the following test. I created a test where I loop for 10 million times and I have a Deque of 10 million random Integers. Inside the loop I poll one element from and offer a constant element. On my computer, LinkedList is over 10 times slower than ArrayDeque and uses less memory). The reason is that unlike ArrayList, ArrayDeque keeps a pointer to the head of the array so that it doesn't have to move all elements when the head is removed.

Comment: This was in reply to Jeremy. Daniel is right. If I use a List as a queue in the same test, ArrayList is 300 times slower than LinkedList if I reduce both the loop and queue size to 300_000. I'm not even going to try the 10 million times. I guess the mentioned CircularArrayList is similar to ArrayDeque in keeping a pointer to the head instead of shifting elements.

Comment: `ArrayDeque` is likely to be faster than `Stack` when used as a stack, and faster than `LinkedList` when used as a queue.

Comment: Note that akhil_mittal's comment is a quote from the `ArrayDeque` documentation.

Answer (score 88):

It's an efficiency question. `LinkedList` is fast for appending or deleting large elements at the ends of a list, but slow to access a specific element. `ArrayList` is fast for accessing a specific element but can be slow to add to either end, and especially slow to delete in the middle.

[Array vs ArrayList vs LinkedList vs Vector](https://web.archive.org/web/20090204031044/http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article1111.html) goes more in depth, as does
[Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: worth to mention here, that `LinkedList` is fast for adding/removing only at first and last positions - then complexity will be O(1), but adding in the middle still will be O(n), because we need to run through approx n/2 elements of `LinkedList`.

Comment: Is it, though?  [Why is an ArrayList always faster than a LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69851017) found that adding 10M items to an ArrayList was faster than adding 10M items to a LinkedList.  (i.e. ArrayList is faster when adding at the end, amortized over having to realloc sometimes.)

Answer (score 62):

Correct or Incorrect: Please execute test locally and decide for yourself!

Edit/Remove is faster in `LinkedList` than `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList`, backed by `Array`, which needs to be double the size, is worse in large volume application.

Below is the unit test result for each operation.Timing is given in Nanoseconds.

---

```
Operation                       ArrayList                      LinkedList  

AddAll   (Insert)               101,16719                      2623,29291 

Add      (Insert-Sequentially)  152,46840                      966,62216

Add      (insert-randomly)      36527                          29193

remove   (Delete)               20,56,9095                     20,45,4904

contains (Search)               186,15,704                     189,64,981
```

---

Here's the code:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListVsLinkedList {
    private static final int MAX = 500000;
    String[] strings = maxArray();

    ////////////// ADD ALL ////////////////////////////////////////
    @Test
    public void arrayListAddAll() {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(MAX);

        watch.start();
        arrayList.addAll(stringList);
        watch.totalTime("Array List addAll() = ");//101,16719 Nanoseconds
    }

    @Test
    public void linkedListAddAll() throws Exception {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);

        watch.start();
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        linkedList.addAll(stringList);
        watch.totalTime("Linked List addAll() = ");  //2623,29291 Nanoseconds
    }

    //Note: ArrayList is 26 time faster here than LinkedList for addAll()

    ///////////////// INSERT /////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Test
    public void arrayListAdd() {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(MAX);

        watch.start();
        for (String string : strings)
            arrayList.add(string);
        watch.totalTime("Array List add() = ");//152,46840 Nanoseconds
    }

    @Test
    public void linkedListAdd() {
        Watch watch = new Watch();

        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        watch.start();
        for (String string : strings)
            linkedList.add(string);
        watch.totalTime("Linked List add() = ");  //966,62216 Nanoseconds
    }

    //Note: ArrayList is 9 times faster than LinkedList for add sequentially

    /////////////////// INSERT IN BETWEEN ///////////////////////////////////////

    @Test
    public void arrayListInsertOne() {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(MAX + MAX / 10);
        arrayList.addAll(stringList);

        String insertString0 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 10);
        String insertString1 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 20);
        String insertString2 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 30);
        String insertString3 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 40);

        watch.start();

        arrayList.add(insertString0);
        arrayList.add(insertString1);
        arrayList.add(insertString2);
        arrayList.add(insertString3);

        watch.totalTime("Array List add() = ");//36527
    }

    @Test
    public void linkedListInsertOne() {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        linkedList.addAll(stringList);

        String insertString0 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 10);
        String insertString1 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 20);
        String insertString2 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 30);
        String insertString3 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 40);

        watch.start();

        linkedList.add(insertString0);
        linkedList.add(insertString1);
        linkedList.add(insertString2);
        linkedList.add(insertString3);

        watch.totalTime("Linked List add = ");//29193
    }


    //Note: LinkedList is 3000 nanosecond faster than ArrayList for insert randomly.

    ////////////////// DELETE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Test
    public void arrayListRemove() throws Exception {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(MAX);

        arrayList.addAll(stringList);
        String searchString0 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 10);
        String searchString1 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 20);

        watch.start();
        arrayList.remove(searchString0);
        arrayList.remove(searchString1);
        watch.totalTime("Array List remove() = ");//20,56,9095 Nanoseconds
    }

    @Test
    public void linkedListRemove() throws Exception {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        linkedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));

        String searchString0 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 10);
        String searchString1 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 20);

        watch.start();
        linkedList.remove(searchString0);
        linkedList.remove(searchString1);
        watch.totalTime("Linked List remove = ");//20,45,4904 Nanoseconds
    }

    //Note: LinkedList is 10 millisecond faster than ArrayList while removing item.

    ///////////////////// SEARCH ///////////////////////////////////////////
    @Test
    public void arrayListSearch() throws Exception {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(MAX);

        arrayList.addAll(stringList);
        String searchString0 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 10);
        String searchString1 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 20);

        watch.start();
        arrayList.contains(searchString0);
        arrayList.contains(searchString1);
        watch.totalTime("Array List addAll() time = ");//186,15,704
    }

    @Test
    public void linkedListSearch() throws Exception {
        Watch watch = new Watch();
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        linkedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));

        String searchString0 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 10);
        String searchString1 = getString(true, MAX / 2 + 20);

        watch.start();
        linkedList.contains(searchString0);
        linkedList.contains(searchString1);
        watch.totalTime("Linked List addAll() time = ");//189,64,981
    }

    //Note: Linked List is 500 Milliseconds faster than ArrayList

    class Watch {
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;

        public void start() {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        private void stop() {
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        public void totalTime(String s) {
            stop();
            System.out.println(s + (endTime - startTime));
        }
    }


    private String[] maxArray() {
        String[] strings = new String[MAX];
        Boolean result = Boolean.TRUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            strings[i] = getString(result, i);
            result = !result;
        }
        return strings;
    }

    private String getString(Boolean result, int i) {
        return String.valueOf(result) + i + String.valueOf(!result);
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayList need not to be doubled, to be precise. Please check the sources first.

Comment: It should be noted that your example is flawed... You are removing from string of between: 18 + [2, 12] bytes ("true0false", "true500000false"), on average 25 bytes, which are the sizes of the elements in the middle. It's known that as element byte size increases linked list performs better, as list size increases, a contiguous array(list) will do better. Most importantly, you are doing .equals() on strings - which is not a cheap operation. If you instead used integers, I think there would be a difference.

Comment: - and that's probably also why there is so little difference for remove/contains.

Comment: "... *is worse in large volume application*": This is a misunderstanding. `LinkedList` has far more memory overhead because for every element there is a node object with five fields. On many systems that makes 20 bytes overhead. The average memory overhead per element for `ArrayList` is one and a half word, which makes 6 bytes, and 8 bytes in the worst case.

Comment: I've done a better version of your benchmark [here, with results](https://gist.github.com/svanoort/4256d1801d97a2b7eef3) - the append-on-end performance for the arraylist is artificially low for yours, because addAll is giving a storage array of EXACTLY initial size, so the first insert always triggers an arraycopy.  Also, this includes warmup cycles to allow for JIT compilation before data is collected.

Comment: `Edit/Remove is faster in LinkedList than ArrayList.` That's a bit too simplified. It depends heavily on where the removal is happening, if it is at the end then ArrayList will be faster, because there is no extra object that has to be GCed at some point.

Comment: `ArrayList, backed by Array, which needs to be double the size, is worse in large volume application.` The opposite is true. An array has much less overhead than an additional object created for _each element in the list_, which is what linkedList does.

Comment: LinkedList has a specific (if short) set of uses.  Try performance of deleting WHILE you are iterating over a linked list (iterator.remove()).  The performance difference should be immense.  Also create a list of a few million items using only "addFirst" and see what you get. (ArrayList obviously shouldn't even have an add first because it's such a dumb thing to do on an arraylist.)

Comment: @BillK since Java 8, you can use `removeIf(element -> condition)` where it fits, which can be significantly faster for an `ArrayList`, compared to looping and removing via iterator, as it is not required to shift the entire remainder for every individual element. Whether this performs better or worse than `LinkedList` depends on the particular scenario, as a `LinkedList` is O(1) in theory, but removing just a single node requires several memory accesses, which can easily exceed the number needed for the `ArrayList` when removing a significant number of elements.

Comment: What does `189,64,981` mean?  Is `,` being used as a decimal point?  If so, why are there two of them in one number?  Are these 3 separate times for 3 separate operations, all in nanoseconds?  Also, if you'd picked something where each compare wasn't so expensive (like string search), you'd probably have found ArrayList faster for searching.

Comment: I agree with @PeterCordes, the timing table is completely meaningless thanks to the confusing commas. I suppose the numbers are whole numbers (no computer measures sub-nanosecond), but there is no obvious pattern in the comma placement.

Comment: @Clashsoft: nitpick: timing granularity is somewhat finer than 1 ns on modern x86 CPUs. 
 A nanosecond is 4 clock cycles for a 4 GHz CPU, and the usual clock-source of choice (RDTSC) ticks at the reference frequency which is usually about the rated non-turbo frequency.  (e.g. my 4.0 GHz i7-6700k has a TSC frequency of 4008 MHz).  Timing overhead is about 20 cycles though, and more with lfence barriers to make sure OoO exec doesn't distort timing.  But if you time a repeat loop and then find the *average* per iteration, you can get accurate sub-nanosecond times for single insns like InstLatx64

Comment: @Clashsoft: But for operations involving several instructions at least, with potential cache misses, at most 1 digit after the decimal place makes sense if you're doing a per-operation average cost of a few ns.  But it's not like times add up linearly over such small chunks anyway on OoO exec CPUs; at that scale a realistic cost model has 3 dimensions: front-end cost, critical path latency, and back-end throughput.  [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391)

Answer (score 58):

`ArrayList` is essentially an array. `LinkedList` is implemented as a double linked list.

The `get` is pretty clear. O(1) for `ArrayList`, because `ArrayList` allow random access by using index. O(n) for `LinkedList`, because it needs to find the index first. Note: there are different versions of `add` and `remove`.

`LinkedList` is faster in add and remove, but slower in get. In brief, `LinkedList` should be preferred if:

1. there are no large number of random access of element
2. there are a large number of add/remove operations

=== **ArrayList** ===

- add(E e)

  - add at the end of ArrayList
  - require memory resizing cost.
  - O(n) worst, O(1) amortized
- add(int index, E element)

  - add to a specific index position
  - require shifting & possible memory resizing cost
  - O(n)
- remove(int index)

  - remove a specified element
  - require shifting & possible memory resizing cost
  - O(n)
- remove(Object o)

  - remove the first occurrence of the specified element from this list
  - need to search the element first, and then shifting & possible memory resizing cost
  - O(n)

=== **LinkedList** ===

- add(E e)

  - add to the end of the list
  - O(1)
- add(int index, E element)

  - insert at specified position
  - need to find the position first
  - O(n)
- remove()

  - remove first element of the list
  - O(1)
- remove(int index)

  - remove element with specified index
  - need to find the element first
  - O(n)
- remove(Object o)

  - remove the first occurrence of the specified element
  - need to find the element first
  - O(n)

Here is a figure from [programcreek.com](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-vs-vector/) (`add` and `remove` are the first type, i.e., add an element at the end of the list and remove the element at the specified position in the list.):

[image]

Comment: "LinkedList is faster than add/remove". Wrong, check the answer above http://stackoverflow.com/a/7507740/638670

Answer (score 55):

**TL;DR** due to modern computer architecture, `ArrayList` will be significantly more efficient for nearly any possible use-case - and therefore `LinkedList` should be avoided except some very unique and extreme cases.

---

In theory, LinkedList has an O(1) for the `add(E element)`

Also adding an element in the mid of a list should be very efficient.

Practice is very different, as LinkedList is a **Cache Hostile** Data structure. From performance POV - there are very little cases where `LinkedList` could be better performing than the *Cache-friendly* `ArrayList`.

Here are results of a benchmark testing inserting elements in random locations. As you can see - the array list if much more efficient, although in theory each insert in the middle of the list will require "move" the *n* later elements of the array (lower values are better):

[image]

Working on a later generation hardware (bigger, more efficient caches) - the results are even more conclusive:

[image]

LinkedList takes much more time to accomplish the same job. [source](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/java-galore-linkedlist-vs-arraylist-vs-dynamicintarray/) [Source Code](https://ideone.com/JOJ05)

There are two main reasons for this:

1. **Mainly** - that the nodes of the `LinkedList` are scattered randomly across the memory. RAM ("Random Access Memory") isn't really random and blocks of memory need to be fetched to cache. This operation takes time, and when such fetches happen frequently - the memory pages in the cache need to be replaced all the time -> Cache misses -> Cache is not efficient.
   `ArrayList` elements are stored on continuous memory - which is exactly what the modern CPU architecture is optimizing for.
2. **Secondary** `LinkedList` required to hold back/forward pointers, which means 3 times the memory consumption per value stored compared to `ArrayList`.

[DynamicIntArray](https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/master/java/core/src/java/org/apache/orc/impl/DynamicIntArray.java), btw, is a custom ArrayList implementation holding `Int` (primitive type) and not Objects - hence all data is really stored adjacently - hence even more efficient.

A key elements to remember is that the cost of fetching memory block, is more significant than the cost accessing a single memory cell. That's why reader 1MB of sequential memory is up to x400 times faster than reading this amount of data from different blocks of memory:

```
Latency Comparison Numbers (~2012)
----------------------------------
L1 cache reference                           0.5 ns
Branch mispredict                            5   ns
L2 cache reference                           7   ns                      14x L1 cache
Mutex lock/unlock                           25   ns
Main memory reference                      100   ns                      20x L2 cache, 200x L1 cache
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy             3,000   ns        3 us
Send 1K bytes over 1 Gbps network       10,000   ns       10 us
Read 4K randomly from SSD*             150,000   ns      150 us          ~1GB/sec SSD
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory     250,000   ns      250 us
Round trip within same datacenter      500,000   ns      500 us
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*     1,000,000   ns    1,000 us    1 ms  ~1GB/sec SSD, 4X memory
Disk seek                           10,000,000   ns   10,000 us   10 ms  20x datacenter roundtrip
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk    20,000,000   ns   20,000 us   20 ms  80x memory, 20X SSD
Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA    150,000,000   ns  150,000 us  150 ms
```

Source: [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)

Just to make the point even clearer, please check the benchmark of adding elements to the beginning of the list. This is a use-case where, in-theory, the `LinkedList` should really shine, and `ArrayList` should present poor or even worse-case results:

[image]

Note: this is a benchmark of the C++ Std lib, but my previous experience shown the C++ and Java results are very similar. [Source Code](https://ideone.com/DDEJF)

Copying a sequential bulk of memory is an operation optimized by the modern CPUs - changing theory and actually making, again, `ArrayList`/`Vector` much more efficient

---

Credits: All benchmarks posted here are created by [Kjell Hedström](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kjellkod/). Even more data can be found on [his blog](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/)

Comment: I wouldn't call a queue unique or extreme! A fifo queue is much easier implemented on a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList.  It's actually a nightmare on an ArrayList as you have to track your own start, stop and do your own reallocating, you might as well use an array, but a Linked List IS a fifo.  I'm not sure about Java's implementation, but a LinkedList can do O(1) for both queue and dequeue operations (Requires a special pointer to the tail element for the remove, which I assume java has but I haven't double-checked.)

Comment: inserting into the middle of a `ArrayList` array uses the native method  `java.lang.System.arraycopy()` which is written in C++ in the OpenJDK. so while in theory a `LinkedList` has less work to do in practice there are so many extra-linguistic mechanisms that make "Big O" largely irrelevant. Particularly how cache friendly things are as per this excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks, but something isn't right with the last benchmark. 1) Why "list" duration even grows? If elements are always inserted at the start (0 index), it doesn't depend on size. And if you meant inserting around the start, then how close this "around" is plays big role - in Java, inserting 1000th element into prebuilt 100_000 array (multiple times) is still faster for LinkedList, and only becomes slower when you get closer to end. 2) So right now around-start-insertion in Java is still faster for LinkedList. Though, I'd advise trick here - just reverse the list before working with it.

Answer (score 38):

`ArrayList` is randomly accessible, while `LinkedList` is really cheap to expand and remove elements from. For most cases, `ArrayList` is fine.

Unless you've created large lists and measured a bottleneck, you'll probably never need to worry about the difference.

Comment: LinkedList is not cheap to add elements to.  It is almost always quicker to add a million elements to an ArrayList than to add them to a LinkedList.  And most lists in real-world code are not even a million elements long.

Comment: At any given point, you know the cost of adding an item to your LinkedList.  The ArrayList you do not (in general).  Adding a single item to an ArrayList containing a million items *could* take a very long time -- it's an O(n) operation plus double the storage unless you preallocated space.  Adding an item to a LinkedList is O(1).  My last statement stands.

Comment: Adding a single item to an ArrayList is O(1) no matter it is 1 million or 1 billion. Adding an item to a LinkedList is also O(1). "Adding" means ADDING TO THE END.

Comment: You must've read the implementation differently than I do.  In my experience, copying a 1 billion element array takes longer than copying a 1 million element array.

Comment: when you add element you add it at the end of the array. there is no copying at all. Copying (shifting) happens when you INSERT into the array.

Comment: @kachanov you must misunderstand Dustin. Unless you have declared an array of 1 billion items you will eventually need to resize your array in which case you will need to copy all elements into a new bigger array hence sometimes you will get O (N) however with a linked list you will always get O (1)

Comment: @Stan R, you must have misunderstood me. If I declare an arry of 1 billion items and adding 99999th item at the end, there is no copying to a bigger array and no resizing.

Comment: @Dustin:For `LinkedList` class , I see in Oracle JDK-8 that methods with label - **Positional Access Operations** are implemented - `public E get(int index)` , `public E set(int index, E element)` , `public void add(int index, E element)`  & `public E remove(int index)`  so I am confused about your statement that only **ArrayList is randomly accessible**. even though you haven't specifically said that LinkedList is not randomly accessible but I guess, you meant that.

Comment: Dustin is of course correct that adding to the end of an `ArrayList` is O(n) in the worst case.  Most of the other commenters are talking about the O(1) amortized complexity of the same operation.  So adding to the end of an `ArrayList` might be faster on average.

Answer (score 30):

You can use one over the other based on the time complexities of the operations that you'd perform on that particular List.

```
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|
|      Operation      |     ArrayList       |     LinkedList     |   Winner   |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|
|     get(index)      |       O(1)          |         O(n)       | ArrayList  |
|                     |                     |  n/4 steps in avg  |            |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|
|      add(E)         |       O(1)          |         O(1)       | LinkedList |
|                     |---------------------|--------------------|            |
|                     | O(n) in worst case  |                    |            |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|
|    add(index, E)    |       O(n)          |         O(n)       | LinkedList |
|                     |     n/2 steps       |      n/4 steps     |            |
|                     |---------------------|--------------------|            |
|                     |                     |  O(1) if index = 0 |            |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|
|  remove(index, E)   |       O(n)          |         O(n)       | LinkedList |
|                     |---------------------|--------------------|            |
|                     |     n/2 steps       |      n/4 steps     |            |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|
|  Iterator.remove()  |       O(n)          |         O(1)       | LinkedList |
|  ListIterator.add() |                     |                    |            |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------|


|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
|              ArrayList               |            LinkedList             |
|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
|     Allows fast read access          |   Retrieving element takes O(n)   |
|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
|   Adding an element require shifting | o(1) [but traversing takes time]  |
|       all the later elements         |                                   |
|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
|   To add more elements than capacity |
|    new array need to be allocated    |
|--------------------------------------|
```

Comment: The ArrayDeque balances things a bit more towards the arrays since insert/remove front/back are all O(1) the only thing Linked List still wins at is adding/removing while traversing (the Iterator operations).

Answer (score 26):

If your code has `add(0)` and `remove(0)`, use a `LinkedList` and it's prettier `addFirst()` and `removeFirst()` methods. Otherwise, use `ArrayList`.

And of course, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [ImmutableList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) is your best friend.

Comment: For small lists, ArrayList.add(0) is still always going to be faster than LinkedList.addFirst().

Comment: @Porculus I am constantly hearing this argument that for small lists ArrayList.add(0) will be faster, this small is how much small? 10 elements, 10 million, ?

Comment: @garg10may small is less than 10.

Comment: @Porculus small means less than the max capacity of the internal array underlying the ArrayList.

Comment: As of JDK 21, all lists (including ArrayList) have addFirst/addLast, getFirst/getLast, and removeFirst/removeLast methods. On ArrayList the implementation of addFirst(e) is essentially add(0, e) but if you're after prettiness these methods are all on ArrayList now.

Answer (score 24):

Let's compare LinkedList and ArrayList w.r.t. below parameters:

### 1. Implementation

> *ArrayList* is the resizable array implementation of list interface , while
>
> *LinkedList* is the Doubly-linked list implementation of the list interface.

---

### 2. Performance

- #### get(int index) or search operation

  > *ArrayList* get(int index) operation runs in constant time i.e O(1)  while
  >
  > *LinkedList* get(int index) operation run time is O(n) .

  The reason behind *ArrayList* being faster than LinkedList is that ArrayList uses an index based system for its elements as it internally uses an array data structure, on the other hand,

  *LinkedList* does not provide index-based access for its elements as it iterates either from the beginning or end (whichever is closer) to retrieve the node at the specified element index.
- #### insert() or add(Object) operation

  > Insertions in *LinkedList* are generally fast as compare to ArrayList. In LinkedList adding or insertion is O(1) operation .
  >
  > While in *ArrayList*, if the array is the full i.e worst case,  there is an extra cost of resizing array and copying elements to the new array, which makes runtime of add operation in ArrayList O(n), otherwise it is O(1).
- #### remove(int) operation

  Remove operation in LinkedList is generally the same as ArrayList i.e. O(n).

  > In *LinkedList*, there are two overloaded remove methods. one is remove() without any parameter which removes the head of the list and runs in constant time O(1). The other overloaded remove method in LinkedList is remove(int) or remove(Object) which removes the Object or int passed as a parameter. This method traverses the LinkedList until it found the Object and unlink it from the original list. Hence this method runtime is O(n).
  >
  > While in *ArrayList* remove(int) method involves copying elements from the old array to new updated array, hence its runtime is O(n).

---

### 3. Reverse  Iterator

> *LinkedList* can be iterated in reverse direction using descendingIterator() while
>
> there is no descendingIterator() in *ArrayList* , so we need to write our own code to iterate over the ArrayList in reverse direction.

---

### 4. Initial Capacity

> If the constructor  is not overloaded, then *ArrayList* creates an empty list of initial capacity 10, while
>
> *LinkedList*  only constructs the empty list without any initial capacity.

---

### 5. Memory Overhead

> Memory overhead in *LinkedList* is more as compared to ArrayList as a node in LinkedList needs to maintain the addresses of the next and previous node. While
>
> In *ArrayList*  each index only holds the actual object(data).

---

[Source](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/04/difference-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist-in-java-example.html)

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old post, but I honestly can't believe nobody mentioned that `LinkedList` implements `Deque`.  Just look at the methods in `Deque` (and `Queue`); if you want a fair comparison, try running `LinkedList` against `ArrayDeque` and do a feature-for-feature comparison.

Answer (score 21):

Here is the Big-O notation in both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` and also `CopyOnWrite-ArrayList`:

**ArrayList**

```
get                 O(1)
add                 O(1)
contains            O(n)
next                O(1)
remove              O(n)
iterator.remove     O(n)
```

**LinkedList**

```
get                 O(n)
add                 O(1)
contains            O(n)
next                O(1)
remove              O(1)
iterator.remove     O(1)
```

**CopyOnWrite-ArrayList**

```
get                 O(1)
add                 O(n)
contains            O(n)
next                O(1)
remove              O(n)
iterator.remove     O(n)
```

Based on these you have to decide what to choose. :)

Comment: >>>> ArrayList add --> O(1) <- not tru. In some cases ArrayList will have to grow to add one more element

Comment: LinkedList remove is not O(1), it would need to search for the element to be removed, therefore worst case O(n) and average O(n/2)

Comment: Neither is `LinkedList.add()`, although most of the answers here say so.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the other good arguments above, you should notice `ArrayList` implements `RandomAccess` interface, while `LinkedList` implements `Queue`.

So, somehow they address slightly different problems, with difference of efficiency and behavior (see their list of methods).

Answer (score 11):

It depends upon what operations you will be doing more on the List.

`ArrayList` is faster to access an indexed value. It is much worse when inserting or deleting objects.

To find out more, read any article that talks about the difference between arrays and linked lists.

Comment: To find out more do not read, just write the code. and you will find out that ArrayList implementation is faster then LinkedList in insertion and deletion.

Answer (score 10):

See [the Java Tutorials - List Implementations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

Comment: Hi @chharvey , Link only answers get 6 Upvotes ? Please add some points that could support the link .What if oracle changes their link?

Answer (score 9):

An important feature of a linked list (which I didn't read in another answer) is the concatenation of two lists. With an array this is O(n) (+ overhead of some reallocations) with a linked list this is only O(1) or O(2) ;-)

**Important**: For Java its `LinkedList` this is not true! See [Is there a fast concat method for linked list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2494031/587642)

Comment: How is that? This may be true with linked list data structures but not a Java LinkList object. You can't just point a `next` from one list to the first node in the second list. The only way is to use `addAll()` which adds elements sequentially, though it is better than looping through and calling `add()` for each element. To do this quickly in O(1) you would need a compositing class (like org.apache.commons.collections.collection.CompositeCollection) but then this would work for any kind of List/Collection.

Comment: yes, true. I edited the answer accordingly. but see this answer for 'how' to do it with LinkedList: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494031/is-there-a-fast-concat-method-for-linked-list-in-java/2494884#2494884

Answer (score 9):

An array list is essentially an array with methods to add items etc. (and you should use a generic list instead). It is a collection of items which can be accessed through an indexer  (for example [0]). It implies a progression from one item to the next.

A linked list specifies a progression from one item to the next (Item a -> item b).  You can get the same effect with an array list, but a linked list absolutely says what item is supposed to follow the previous one.

Answer (score 8):

ArrayList and LinkedList have their own pros and cons.

ArrayList uses contiguous memory address compared to LinkedList which uses pointers toward the next node. So when you want to look up an element in an ArrayList is faster than doing n iterations with LinkedList.

On the other hand, insertion and deletion in a LinkedList are much easier because you just have to change the pointers whereas an ArrayList implies the use of shift operation for any insertion or deletion.

If you have frequent retrieval operations in your app use an ArrayList. If you have frequent insertion and deletion use a LinkedList.

Answer (score 8):

**1) Underlying Data Structure**

The first difference between ArrayList and LinkedList comes with the fact that ArrayList is backed by Array while LinkedList is backed by LinkedList. This will lead to further differences in performance.

**2) LinkedList implements Deque**

Another difference between ArrayList and LinkedList is that apart from the List interface, LinkedList also implements Deque interface, which provides first in first out operations for `add()` and `poll()` and several other Deque functions. 3) Adding elements in ArrayList Adding element in ArrayList is O(1) operation if it doesn't trigger re-size of Array, in which case it becomes O(log(n)), On the other hand, appending an element in LinkedList is O(1) operation, as it doesn't require any navigation.

**4) Removing an element from a position**

In order to remove an element from a particular index e.g. by calling `remove(index)`, ArrayList performs a copy operation which makes it close to O(n) while LinkedList needs to traverse to that point which also makes it O(n/2), as it can traverse from either direction based upon proximity.

**5) Iterating over ArrayList or LinkedList**

Iteration is the O(n) operation for both LinkedList and ArrayList where n is a number of an element.

**6) Retrieving element from a position**

The `get(index)` operation is O(1) in ArrayList while its O(n/2) in LinkedList, as it needs to traverse till that entry. Though, in Big O notation O(n/2) is just O(n) because we ignore constants there.

**7) Memory**

LinkedList uses a wrapper object, Entry, which is a static nested class for storing data and two nodes next and previous while ArrayList just stores data in Array.

So memory requirement seems less in the case of ArrayList than LinkedList except for the case where Array performs the re-size operation when it copies content from one Array to another.

If Array is large enough it may take a lot of memory at that point and trigger Garbage collection, which can slow response time.

From all the above differences between ArrayList vs LinkedList, It looks ArrayList is the better choice than LinkedList in almost all cases, except when you do a frequent `add()` operation than `remove()`, or `get()`.

It's easier to modify a linked list than ArrayList, especially if you are adding or removing elements from start or end because linked list internally keeps references of those positions and they are accessible in O(1) time.

In other words, you don't need to traverse through the linked list to reach the position where you want to add elements, in that case, addition becomes O(n) operation. For example, inserting or deleting an element in the middle of a linked list.

In my opinion, use ArrayList over LinkedList for most of the practical purpose in Java.

Comment: I think this is the best stated answer of the entire group here.  It's accurate and informative.  I would suggest changing the last line--at the end add "aside from queues" which are very important structures that really don't make sense for a linked list at all.

Answer (score 6):

I have read the responses, but there is one scenario where I always use a LinkedList over an ArrayList that I want to share to hear opinions:

Every time I had a method that returns a list of data obtained from a DB I always use a LinkedList.

My rationale was that because it is impossible to know exactly how many results am I getting, there will be not memory wasted (as in ArrayList with the difference between the capacity and actual number of elements), and there would be no time wasted trying to duplicate the capacity.

As far a ArrayList, I agree that at least you should always use the constructor with the initial capacity, to minimize the duplication of the arrays as much as possible.

Comment: `LinkedList` has a much higher overhead per element (3 pointers per element). `ArrayList` has 1 pointer per element. So even if the `ArrayList` is only half filled, it will never have more overhead than `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 6):

`ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both implements `List interface`  and their methods and results are almost identical. However there are few differences between them which make one better over another depending on the requirement.

### ArrayList Vs LinkedList

1) `Search:` `ArrayList` search operation is pretty fast compared to the `LinkedList` search operation. `get(int index)` in `ArrayList` gives the performance of `O(1)` while `LinkedList` performance is `O(n)`.

`Reason:` `ArrayList` maintains index based system for its elements as it uses array data structure implicitly which makes it faster for searching an element in the list. On the other side `LinkedList` implements doubly linked list which requires the traversal through all the elements for searching an element.

2) `Deletion:` `LinkedList` remove operation gives `O(1)` performance while `ArrayList` gives variable performance: `O(n)` in worst case (while removing first element) and `O(1)` in best case (While removing last element).

> Conclusion: LinkedList element deletion is faster compared to
>   ArrayList.

Reason: LinkedList’s each element maintains two pointers (addresses) which points to the both neighbor elements in the list. Hence removal only requires change in the pointer location in the two neighbor nodes (elements) of the node which is going to be removed. While In ArrayList all the elements need to be shifted to fill out the space created by removed element.

3) `Inserts Performance:` `LinkedList` add method gives `O(1)` performance while `ArrayList` gives `O(n)` in worst case. Reason is same as explained for remove.

4) `Memory Overhead:` `ArrayList` maintains indexes and element data while `LinkedList` maintains element data and two pointers for neighbor nodes

> hence the memory consumption is high in LinkedList comparatively.

### There are few similarities between these classes which are as follows:

- Both ArrayList and LinkedList are implementation of List interface.
- They both maintain the elements insertion order which means while displaying ArrayList and LinkedList elements the result set would be having the same order in which the elements got inserted into the List.
- Both these classes are non-synchronized and can be made synchronized explicitly by using Collections.synchronizedList method.
- The `iterator` and `listIterator` returned by these classes are `fail-fast` (if list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the `iterator’s` own remove or add methods, the iterator will `throw` a `ConcurrentModificationException`).

### When to use LinkedList and when to use ArrayList?

- As explained above the insert and remove operations give good performance `(O(1))` in `LinkedList` compared to `ArrayList(O(n))`.

  > Hence if there is a requirement of frequent addition and deletion in application then LinkedList is a best choice.
- Search (`get method`) operations are fast in `Arraylist (O(1))` but not in `LinkedList (O(n))`

  > so If there are less add and remove operations and more search operations requirement, ArrayList would be your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

Operation get(i) in ArrayList is faster than LinkedList, because:
**ArrayList:** Resizable-array implementation of the List interface
**LinkedList:** Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces

Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

Answer (score 4):

Both `remove()` and `insert()` have a runtime efficiency of O(n) for both ArrayLists and LinkedLists. However, the reason behind the linear processing time comes from two very different reasons:

In an ArrayList, you get to the element in O(1), but actually removing or inserting something makes it O(n) because all the following elements need to be changed.

In a LinkedList, it takes O(n) to actually get to the desired element, because we have to start at the very beginning until we reach the desired index. Actually removing or inserting is constant, because we only have to change 1 reference for `remove()` and 2 references for `insert()`.

Which of the two is faster for inserting and removing depends on where it happens. If we are closer to the beginning the LinkedList will be faster, because we have to go through relatively few elements. If we are closer to the end an ArrayList will be faster, because we get there in constant time and only have to change the few remaining elements that follow it. When done precisely in the middle the LinkedList will be faster because going through n elements is quicker than moving n values.

Bonus: While there is no way of making these two methods O(1) for an ArrayList, there actually is a way to do this in LinkedLists. Let's say we want to go through the entire List removing and inserting elements on our way. Usually, you would start from the very beginning for each element using the LinkedList, we could also "save" the current element we're working on with an Iterator. With the help of the Iterator, we get an O(1) efficiency for `remove()` and `insert()` when working in a LinkedList. Making it the only performance benefit I'm aware of where a LinkedList is always better than an ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

One of the tests I saw on here only conducts the test once.  But what I have noticed is that you need to run these tests many times and eventually their times will converge.  Basically the JVM needs to warm up.  For my particular use case I needed to add/remove items to a list that grows to about 500 items.  In my tests `LinkedList` came out faster, with `LinkedList` coming in around 50,000 NS and `ArrayList` coming in at around 90,000 NS... give or take.  See the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> times = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        times.add(doIt());
    }
    System.out.println("avg = " + (times.stream().mapToLong(x -> x).average()));
}

static long doIt() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
    //uncomment line below to test with ArrayList
    //list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        it.remove();
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long diff = end - start;
    //uncomment to see the JVM warmup and get faster for the first few iterations
    //System.out.println(diff)
    return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList extends AbstractList and implements the List Interface. ArrayList is dynamic array.
It can be said that it was basically created to overcome the drawbacks of arrays
The LinkedList class extends AbstractSequentialList and implements List,Deque, and Queue interface.

Performance
`arraylist.get()` is  O(1) whereas `linkedlist.get()` is O(n) 
`arraylist.add()` is  O(1) and `linkedlist.add()` is 0(1)
`arraylist.contains()` is O(n) and`linkedlist.contains()` is O(n) 
`arraylist.next()` is O(1) and `linkedlist.next()` is O(1)
`arraylist.remove()` is O(n) whereas `linkedlist.remove()` is O(1)
In arraylist
`iterator.remove()` is O(n)
 whereas In linkedlist 
`iterator.remove()`is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is if I need a `Collection` (i.e. doesn't need to be a `List`) then use `ArrayList` if you know the size in advance, or can know the size confidently, or know that it won't vary much. If you need random access (i.e. you use `get(index)`) then avoid `LinkedList`. Basically, use `LinkedList` only if you don't need index access and don't know the (approximate) size of the collection you're allocating. Also if you're going to be making lots of additions and removals (again through the `Collection` interface) then LinkedList may be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any mention of this yet (maybe I missed it among the 30+ answers...), but you should ALWAYS prefer an `ArrayList` over a `LinkedList` if you know what the final size of your collection will be. You can take advantage of the `new ArrayList<>(size)` to ensure all insertions are O(1) (as long as you only add up to `size` elements).

And yes, I'm aware `ImmutableCollection`s are technically the correct choice for fixed size collections - but they become quite the pain in the ass if you ever decide to modify your list down the line (`remove()`, `sublist()` modifications, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

When should I use `LinkedList`? When working with stacks mostly, or when working with buffers.
When should I use `ArrayList`? Only when working with indexes,  otherwise you can use HashTable with linked list, then you get:

### Hash table + linked list

- Access by key **O(1),**
- Insert by key **O(1),**
- Remove by key **O(1)**
- and there is a trick to implement RemoveAll / SetAll with O(1) when using versioning

It seems like a good solution, and in most of the cases it is, how ever you should know:
HashTable takes a lot of disc space, so when you need to manage 1,000,000 elements list it can become a thing that matters. This can happen in server implementations, in clients it is rarely the case.

Also take a look at [Red-Black-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

- Random access **Log(n),**
- Insert **Log(n),**
- Remove **Log(n)**

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one -1: LinkedList gives O(N) on all of insert, remove and random access because you have to traverse the list to get to the correct point first. Also it might surprise you to learn that hashmap/table use resizing arrays just like ArrayList and given that the most common usage of lists is to just be indexed by a number, using one of those over an ArrayList is the worst idea.

Comment: @Numeron you are right, it wasn't clear what I answered. Indeed when you try accessing linked list by index, it will be O(n), how ever I meant inserting to linked list by items. Then it's O(1) and also interacting over all the list it's same as array list.

Answer (score -10):

First of all use Vector instead ArrayList because you can overrite insureCapasity method ,
in ArrayList is private and add 1.5 size of current array https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity-int-

in many case it can be better that linkedList, the las has big advantage one you insert data with high freqency so size of you list changes very fast and you can't allocate size for number elements. 
In the theory you can get error like not "enough memory"  but  in modern computers you have 16G and swaping disk, so if you list is billoins elements you can fail, comparing 15-20 years ago.

Comment: ```Vector``` is slower compared to ```ArrayList``` because ```Vector``` is thread-safe. The best practice is not using a ```Vector``` unless thread safety is needed. ```Vector``` doubles its size by default, ```ArrayList``` multiplies its size by 3/2. See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471913/java-vector-vs-arraylist-performance-test

Comment: What are you talking about? `ArrayList` [has a public `ensureCapacity` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int)) and always had. So your only reason to use an outdated class does not stand a single reality check.

Comment: From the Vector.java documentation via your own link:  "Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector."

Comment: Could have you checked a performance of Vector ?   Due to my test a few years ago. Vector is faster . I thing because a smaller number of memory allocations. Mutex time is depends of the kernel but it doesn't take a lot of time  roughly 15msec IMHO .