# Besides Inserts what are the advantages of LinkedLists over Lists?

Tags: list, data-structures, linked-list

I suspect that LinkedLists are better than Lists/Arrays for storing sparse data and graphs.

Is this correct? What else are they better than Lists for?

Comment: You would be better off looking this up in a reference work on data structures.

Comment: This might help answer some of your questions, [When to use a linked list over an array/array list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393556/when-to-use-a-linked-list-over-an-array-array-list)

Comment: Where exactly do you see the conceptual difference between a "Linked List" and a "List" (taking the question back if you simply mean "an array as 'traversable container'") ?

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage for linked lists over arrays is that they are recursive structure which is useful in recursive algorithms. Also linked list is dynamic structure while array is a static structure.