# Benefit and disadvantage of linked list or array implementation of list

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list

What are the advantages a Linked-List implementation of a List has over an Array-based implementation of an array and vice-verse?

For starters I know that linked-list uses up more space than an array because it has to use the extra 4 bytes of space to hold a reference to the next node and an array doesn't have to do that. So array uses less space.

Advantage linked-list has over an array implementation is that array has a fixed size at initialization and you have to write code to increase the size of the array so that may be a disadvantage when compared to linked-list implementation.

Any ideas on anything else for advantage-disadvantage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393556/when-to-use-a-linked-list-over-an-array-array-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array, you can access any element if you have the index (constant time complexity O(1) ). But for a list, you have to iterate one by one to access although you have the index (time complexity O(n))

For a list, inserting and deleting an element take constant time (O(1)). But for array, inserting and deleting take O(n) time.

For sorting, the list implementation is better than the array implementation.

Comment: I like your answer because you do a more thorough analysis of the comparison between the 2 implementations of a list. The recommended SO post does more of a comparison between arrays and Linked Lists which is slightly unrelated to my direct question.