# difference between array and list

Tags: c

what is the difference between array and list?

Comment: There are lists in C? I mean, apart from the hundreds of minimalistic book examples of linked lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*In C*, an array is a fixed-size region of contiguous storage containing multiple objects, one after the other. This array is an "object" in the meaning which C gives to the word - basically just some memory that represents something. An object could just be an `int`.

You can distinguish slightly between array *objects*, and array *types*. Often people use array *objects* which are allocated with `malloc`, and used via a pointer to the first element. But C does also have specific types for arrays of different sizes, and also for variable-length-arrays, whose size is set when they are created. VLAs have a slightly misleading name: the size is only "variable" in the sense that it isn't fixed at compile time. It can't change during the lifetime of the object.

So, when I say an array is fixed-size I mean that the size cannot change once the array is created, and this includes VLAs. There is `realloc`, which logically returns a pointer to a new array that replaces the old one, but can sometimes return the same address passed in, having changed the size of the array in place. `realloc` operates on memory allocations, not on arrays in general.

That's what an array is. The C programming language doesn't define anything called a list. Can't really compare something which is well defined, with something that isn't defined ;-) Usually "list" would mean a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), but in some contexts or in other languages it means other things.

For that matter, in other languages "array" could mean other things, although I can't immediately think of a language where it means anything very different from a C array.

If your question really has nothing to do with C, and is a language-agnostic data-structures question, "what is the difference between an array and a linked list?", then it's a duplicate of this:

[Array versus linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166884/array-vs-linked-list)

Comment: "I can't immediately think of a language where [array] means anything very different from a C array."  Look at PHP's "array" data structure; that's the most different I can think of.

Answer (score 7):

Although there is *nothing like a* `list` *in* `C` *per se* but you sure could be talking about a linked lists implementation.

**Array:** Random access, predefine size.
**Linked List:** Sequential access, size at runtime.

Other languages like, say Python, may have have both `list`s and `array`s inbuilt and their meaning may differ.

**Useful comments from below:**

You could add array lists. Lists which internally is an array which is doubled when needed and halved when only 1/4 full. This gives O(1) for add, remove, get(index) amortized. – [lasseespeholt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174574/lasseespeholt)

Python's `list` is not a linked list. And the distinction between Python `list` and `array` is `list` can store anything while array can only store primitive types (`int`, `float`, etc). – [KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm)

Comment: You could add array lists. Lists which internally is an array which is doubled when needed and halved when only 1/4 full. This gives O(1) for add, remove, get(index) amortized.

Comment: Python's "list" is, in fact, what other languages call an array (of dynamic size).

Comment: Guys, with the Python line I was only suggesting there are languages which come with a distinction and inbuilt type.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a standard list in C. There is such a thing in C++, where it is implemented as a [double-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly-linked_list).

The main differences are that arrays have *random access* - you can access any member of the array in `O(1)` time (i.e. if `a` was an array, `a[4]`) and have a pre-set size at compile time. Linked lists have sequential access - to access an element, you have to loop through the list until you get to the element you want (i.e. if `b` was a linked list, to get to the 5th element of `b` you would have to iterate through elements 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4), and the size can be grown and shrunk dynamically.

Comment: @Stephen: Although I might point out that arrays can also have their sizes set at run time using dynamic memory allocation - it doesn't *have* to be defined at compile time, it is up to the programmer to choose

Comment: The size of each element is set at compile time, so the fact that you can dynamically create one doesn't change the fact that lookup is O(1)

Comment: @bguiz As far as I was aware, pure arrays have their sizes set at compilation time. Do you mean doing something like using `malloc` and a pointer to a type to do the dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @Stephen: there are also VLAs in C99. To everyone except Microsoft, C99 is "current" C, and C89 is "old" C. But I think bguiz did just mean `malloc`.

Comment: @Stephen @Steve Jessop : IDK about C, in C++ if you use the `new` operator when initialising an array, it is created on the heap, not the stack, and its size is determined at runtime

Answer (score 2):

1. For array, it has a fixed size like we write, **new int [100]**
   but list does not have a fixed size...it can go on and on
2. Insertion and Deletion is easier in list than in array
   Reason: we can simply use to change the pointers to insert and delete for linked  list but for array insert and deletion needs shiftRight and shiftLeft
3. Linked List uses a dummy head node to avoid special cases of inserting into an empty list, or removing the last node from a list of unit size; and, it uses double links to allow iterating in both directions. The cost of course is the extra space needed to hold the dummy node (minimal cost), and the extra previous link in addition the usual next link for each node (much more significant cost).
   In array, we can add with the help of its random access
4. In Linked list, reference to the tail node is simply header.prev, which gives us ability to append to the list in constant time (without having to iterate to find the tail reference, or having to maintain a separate tail reference).
   But in array, we need to re-size the array before inserting.
5. Array has the flexibility to attain random access unlike Linked List.

Linked list has problems like,

> It consumes extra memory storage for the pointer we are using!
>
> Time complexity of O(n) instead of O(1) like in array
>
> Reverse traversing is difficult for singly linked list and if we use doubly linked list, another pointer means more of extra memory storage
>
> Heap Restriction as well! Memory is allocated only if there is space available in the heap. If insufficient memory then memory won't be created.

Array has problems like,

> a chance of memory wastage or shortage.

Hope this helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

An often under appreciated characteristic of Linked data structures is that you can use them in situations where memory is highly fragmented due to there being no contiguous memory guarantee between elements. For example you could have 100MB of free space but only say a maximum run of free memory of length 10MB. In this case you can only create an an array of size 10MB but perhaps a potentially larger linked list since you would be able to make use of every run of free memory which was large enough to contain a single node.

Answer (score 0):

**array** has only similar data types(i.e.,) they are homogeneous in nature. we can only have an array of strings , integers etc. also the size of array is predefined.
 but in the case of **list** we can have any type of elements. let it be a string integer or combination of both.Also null or duplicate elements are allowed in list. example of list include arraylist , linkedlist.here in list the size can grow or shrink at any time.