# What is the performance tradeoff with BST implemented using linked list or array?

Tags: arrays, performance, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I was just wondering what would be the performance ratio, between binary search tree implemented using a linked and a binary search tree implemented using an array. I just want to know the performance comparisons. I've already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166884/array-vs-linked-list) in stackoverflow.

Comment: can anyone provide some statistical data.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can implement a binary search tree with an array. A binary search tree is like an advanced linked list. In fact, if you use a basic BST (not balancing) and input presorted data, you basically end up with a linked list.