# Is it better to store big number in list?

Tags: python

Is it memory efficient to store big number in list? Why does the following happens?

```
>>> A = 100**100
>>> sys.getsizeof(A)
102
>>> B = [100**100]
>>> sys.getsizeof(B)
40
```

Why size of A and B are not equal?

```
>>> C = [1,100**100]
>>> sys.getsizeof(C)
44
>>> D = [1000**1000, 100**100]
>>> sys.getsizeof(D)
44
```

Why size of C and D are equal?

Comment: try `print sys.getsizeof(B[0])`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247298/size-of-list-in-memory) is some good discussion of how Python lists consume memory

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof()` returns the *shallow* size, i.e. the size of the list object itself but not of the objects it contains.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

If you'd like to compute the *deep* size, it might be worth giving [Pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/) a try:

```
>>> from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
>>> A = 100**100
>>> asizeof(A)
120
>>> B = [100**100]
>>> asizeof(B)
200
```

Thus, on my computer, placing the long inside a list adds 80 bytes of overhead.

Answer (score 9):

The size of A and B are not equal because you've put B into a list.  In this case, A is a long and B is a list type.  C and D are the same size because their numerical contents are the same width inside the list container.

Further, `sys.getsizeof()` [returns the size of the topmost object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) using the `__sizeof__` method, not the size of the items referenced inside of that object.

Comment: This explains a lots. Thank you

Comment: @AerofoilKite no problem at all. NPE's answer really nails it head on.  In the link to the documentation I gave, there's a link to an ActiveState recipe that details stepping through an object to return the "true" size.

Answer (score 4):

from python wiki :

> Its because of that `getsizeof()` Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.

**Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to**.

and in this case B is the name of list and actually a pointer to list ! so `getsizeof()` return the size of a list object , not its content !