# Why is a sorted list bigger than an unsorted list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting, python-internals

I have a list `my_list` (the list contains utf8 strings):

```
>>> len(my_list)
8777
>>> getsizeof(my_list)                     #  <-- note the size
77848
```

For some reason, a sorted list (`my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list)`) uses more memory :

```
>>> len(my_sorted_list)
8777
>>> getsizeof(my_sorted_list)              #  <-- note the size
79104
```

Why is `sorted` returning a list that takes more space in memory than the initial unsorted list?

Comment: As [@Jim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40317620/3124746) pointed out that `sorted` creates new list  you can follow story with [my recent question(list() uses more memory than list comprehension)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018398/list-uses-more-memory-than-list-comprehension) it would give you some python insights.

Comment: @vishes_shell Or also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247298/size-of-list-in-memory (asked in 2011)

Comment: I really liked the charts in your answer to your question @vishes_shell :-). The only issue I see with these sort of questions and answers is that they might *suddenly* become obsolete at some point because we're dealing with an implementation detail :(

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard that's true, although this particular implementation detail has survived the move from python2 to python3.

Comment: @jcuenod True, true. Just take a look at the `dict` though, it's implementation survived for long until [it got a pretty big change in `3.6`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6) ;-).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [Ignacio points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315692/4952130), this is due to Python allocating a bit more memory than required. This is done in order to perform `O(1)` `.appends` on lists.

`sorted` [creates a *new list*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a2d2befd5fafa41ace4358e791f066748906f907/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2105) out of the sequence provided, [sorts it in place](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a2d2befd5fafa41ace4358e791f066748906f907/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2109) and returns it. To create the new list, Python [*extends an empty sized list with the one passed*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4265fa04206b29b3ec653d74a620b0413306023f/Objects/abstract.c#L1856); that results in the observed over-allocation (which happens after calling `list_resize`). You can corroborate the fact that sorting isn't the culprit by using `list.sort`; the *same algorithm is used* without a new list getting created (or, as it's known, it's *performed in-place*). The sizes there, of course, *don't differ*.

It is worth noting that this difference is mostly present when:

- The original list was created with a list-comp (where, if space is available and [*the final `append` doesn't trigger a resize*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a2d2befd5fafa41ace4358e791f066748906f907/Objects/listobject.c#L294), the size is smaller).
- When list literals are used. There  [a `PyList_New` is created based on the number of values on the stack](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13a685e8c58955096933989a5b7fcb56524a921b/Python/ceval.c#L2507) and no appends are made.  *[Direct assigning to the underlying array is performed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a2d2befd5fafa41ace4358e791f066748906f907/Python/ceval.c#L2510)*) which doesn't trigger any resizes and keeps size to its minimum:

So, with a list-comp:

```
l = [i for i in range(10)]

getsizeof(l)          # 192
getsizeof(sorted(l))  # 200
```

Or a list literal:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

getsizeof(l)          # 144
getsizeof(sorted(l))  # 200
```

the sizes are smaller (more so with use of literals).

When creating through `list`, the memory is always over-allocated; Python [*knows the sizes*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a2d2befd5fafa41ace4358e791f066748906f907/Objects/listobject.c#L800) and preempts future modifications by over-allocating a bit based on the size:

```
l = list(range(10))

getsizeof(l)          # 200
getsizeof(sorted(l))  # 200
```

So you get no observed difference in the sizes of the list(s).

---

As a final note, I must point out that this is behavior *specific* the `C` implementation of Python i.e CPython. It's a detail of how the language was implemented and as such, you shouldn't depend on it in any wacky way.

Jython, IronPython, PyPy and any other implementation might/might not have the same behavior.

Answer (score 13):

The [list resize operation](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.2/file/10298f4f42dc/Objects/listobject.c#l25) overallocates in order to amortize appending to the list versus starting with a list preallocated by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Python's code! That's awesome... I would have accepted but the detail in @Jim's answer won me over.