# Why do tuples take less space in memory than lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples, python-internals

A `tuple` takes less memory space in Python:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> a.__sizeof__()
48
```

whereas `list`s takes more memory space:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> b.__sizeof__()
64
```

What happens internally on the Python memory management?

Comment: I am not sure on how this works internally, but the list object at least has more functions like for instance append which the tuple does not have. It therefore makes sense for the tuple as a simpler type of object to be smaller

Comment: I think it also depend on machine to machine ....for me when i check  a = (1,2,3) takes 72 and b = [1,2,3]  takes 88.

Comment: Python tuples are immutable. Mutable objects have extra overhead to deal with runtime changes.

Comment: @Metareven the number of methods a type has does not impact the memory space the instances take. The method list and their code are handled by the object prototype, but instances store only data and internal variables.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I assume you're using CPython and with 64bits (I got the same results on my CPython 2.7 64-bit). There could be differences in other Python implementations or if you have a 32bit Python.

Regardless of the implementation, `list`s are variable-sized while `tuple`s are fixed-size.

So `tuple`s can store the elements directly inside the struct, lists on the other hand need a layer of indirection (it stores a pointer to the elements). This layer of indirection is a pointer, on 64bit systems that's 64bit, hence 8bytes.

But there's another thing that `list`s do: They over-allocate. Otherwise `list.append` would be an `O(n)` operation **always** - to make it amortized `O(1)` (much faster!!!) it over-allocates. But now it has to keep track of the **allocated** size and the **filled** size (`tuple`s only need to store one size, because allocated and filled size are always identical). That means each list has to store another "size" which on 64bit systems is a 64bit integer, again 8 bytes.

So `list`s need at least 16 bytes more memory than `tuple`s. Why did I say "at least"? Because of the over-allocation. Over-allocation means it allocates more space than needed. However, the amount of over-allocation depends on "how" you create the list and the append/deletion history:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.__sizeof__()
64
>>> l.append(4)  # triggers re-allocation (with over-allocation), because the original list is full
>>> l.__sizeof__()
96

>>> l = []
>>> l.__sizeof__()
40
>>> l.append(1)  # re-allocation with over-allocation
>>> l.__sizeof__()
72
>>> l.append(2)  # no re-alloc
>>> l.append(3)  # no re-alloc
>>> l.__sizeof__()
72
>>> l.append(4)  # still has room, so no over-allocation needed (yet)
>>> l.__sizeof__()
72
```

### Images

I decided to create some images to accompany the explanation above. Maybe these are helpful

This is how it (schematically) is stored in memory in your example. I highlighted the differences with red (free-hand) cycles:

[image]

That's actually just an approximation because `int` objects are also Python objects and CPython even reuses small integers, so a probably more accurate representation (although not as readable) of the objects in memory would be:

[image]

Useful links:

- [`tuple` struct in CPython repository for Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/tupleobject.h#L24-L32)
- [`list` struct in CPython repository for Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/listobject.h#L22_L39)
- [`int` struct in CPython repository for Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/intobject.h#L23-L26)

Note that `__sizeof__` doesn't really return the "correct" size! It only returns the size of the stored values. However when you use [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) the result is different:

```
>>> import sys
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
88
>>> sys.getsizeof(t)
72
```

There are 24 "extra" bytes. These are **real**, that's the garbage collector overhead that isn't accounted for in the `__sizeof__` method. That's because you're generally not supposed to use magic methods directly - use the functions that know how to handle them, in this case: [`sys.getsizeof`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/sysmodule.c#L687-L761) (which actually [adds the GC overhead](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/sysmodule.c#L731-L732) to the value returned from `__sizeof__`).

Comment: Re "*So lists need at least 16 bytes more memory than tuples.*", Wouldn't that be 8? One size for tuples and two sizes for lists means one extra size for lists.

Comment: Yes, list has one extra "size" (8 byte) but also stores a pointer (8byte) to the "array of PyObject"s instead of storing them in the struct directly (what the tuple does). 8+8=16.

Comment: Another **useful** link about `list` memory allocation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018398/list-uses-more-memory-than-list-comprehension

Comment: @vishes_shell That's not really related to the question because the code in the question **doesn't over-allocate at all**. But yes it's useful in case you want to know more about the amount of over-allocation when using `list()` or a list comprehension.

Comment: The amount of "wasted" memory is so small that it typically doesn't matter unless you have a huge amount of lists/tuples. If many of the containers are empty, the difference gets bigger, though. An empty tuple is a singleton (at least in CPython) so they take in practice no memory. A new empty list is always a new object that needs its own memory allocation.

Comment: @MSeifert, you mentioned that lists are trying to amortize the append command. Does it mean that tuples do not do that. And, hence, tuples will be slower when you try to append elements to a tuple?

Comment: @user3349993 Tuples are immutable, so you can't append to a tuple or remove an item from a tuple.

Comment: "So tuples can store the elements directly inside the struct, lists on the other hand need a layer of indirection (it stores a pointer to the elements)." This seems wrong. CPython has no concept of "raw" objects, neither as tagged pointers nor value types. The links to the source code also show both `tuple` and `list` storing their content in an array of object *pointers*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the difference is where the array of object pointers is stored. In the case of the tuple the array is inside the struct (`PyObject *ob_item[1]`) - a list stores a pointer (indirection) to the array in the struct (`PyObject **ob_item`). For the tuple it can store the pointers to the tuple elements inside the struct itself, while the list with the indirection has to put them in an array "somewhere else". The "Images" part of the answer actually visually explains it . If you have some suggestions how i could improve the answer so it becomes more clear please let me know

Comment: @MisterMiyagi As an additional comment because it tripped me up (again): The `ob_item[1]` for the tuple struct isn't actually a size-1 array. This is probably just some header-file-stuff so the users get the correct type information and some random value because the size of the array is not known at compile time. There's a comment in the cpython source code about it: "ob_item contains space for 'ob_size' elements"

Answer (score 32):

I'll take a deeper dive into the CPython codebase so we can see how the sizes are actually calculated. *In your specific example*, *no over-allocations have been performed, so I won't touch on that*.

I'm going to use 64-bit values here, as you are.

---

The size for `list`s is calculated from the following function, [`list_sizeof`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/listobject.c#L2471):

```c
static PyObject *
list_sizeof(PyListObject *self)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;

    res = _PyObject_SIZE(Py_TYPE(self)) + self->allocated * sizeof(void*);
    return PyInt_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

Here [`Py_TYPE(self)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Include/object.h#L118) is a macro that grabs the `ob_type` of `self` (returning `PyList_Type`) while  `_PyObject_SIZE` is another macro that grabs [`tp_basicsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_basicsize) from that type. `tp_basicsize` is calculated as `sizeof(PyListObject)` where `PyListObject` is the instance struct.

The [`PyListObject` structure](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/listobject.h#L22) has three fields:

```c
PyObject_VAR_HEAD     # 24 bytes 
PyObject **ob_item;   #  8 bytes
Py_ssize_t allocated; #  8 bytes
```

these have comments (which I trimmed) explaining what they are, follow the link above to read them. [`PyObject_VAR_HEAD`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject_VAR_HEAD) expands into three 8 byte fields (`ob_refcount`, `ob_type` and `ob_size`) so a `24` byte contribution.

So for now `res` is:

```
sizeof(PyListObject) + self->allocated * sizeof(void*)
```

or:

```
40 + self->allocated * sizeof(void*)
```

If the list instance has elements that are allocated. the second part calculates their contribution. `self->allocated`, as it's name implies, holds the number of allocated elements.

Without any elements, the size of lists is calculated to be:

```
>>> [].__sizeof__()
40
```

i.e the size of the instance struct.

---

`tuple` objects don't define a `tuple_sizeof` function. Instead, they use [`object_sizeof`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3644) to calculate their size:

```c
static PyObject *
object_sizeof(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_ssize_t res, isize;

    res = 0;
    isize = self->ob_type->tp_itemsize;
    if (isize > 0)
        res = Py_SIZE(self) * isize;
    res += self->ob_type->tp_basicsize;

    return PyInt_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

This, as for `list`s, grabs the `tp_basicsize` and, if the object has a non-zero `tp_itemsize` (meaning it has variable-length instances), it multiplies the number of items in the tuple (which it gets via [`Py_SIZE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Include/object.h#L119)) with `tp_itemsize`.

`tp_basicsize` again uses `sizeof(PyTupleObject)` where the  [`PyTupleObject` struct contains](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/tupleobject.h#L24):

```c
PyObject_VAR_HEAD       # 24 bytes 
PyObject *ob_item[1];   # 8  bytes
```

So, without any elements (that is, `Py_SIZE` returns `0`) the size of empty tuples is equal to `sizeof(PyTupleObject)`:

```
>>> ().__sizeof__()
24
```

huh? Well, here's an oddity which I haven't found an explanation for, the `tp_basicsize` of `tuple`s is actually calculated as follows:

```c
sizeof(PyTupleObject) - sizeof(PyObject *)
```

why an additional `8` bytes is removed from `tp_basicsize` is something I haven't been able to find out. (See MSeifert's comment for a possible explanation)

---

But, this is basically the difference *in your specific example*. `list`s also keep around a number of allocated elements which helps determine when to over-allocate again.

Now, when additional elements are added, lists do indeed perform this over-allocation in order to achieve O(1) appends. This results in greater sizes as MSeifert's covers nicely in his answer.

Comment: I believe the `ob_item[1]` is mostly a placeholder (so it makes sense it's subtracted from the basicsize). The `tuple` is allocated using [`PyObject_NewVar`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/allocation.html#c.PyObject_NewVar). I haven't figured out the details so that's just an educated guess...

Comment: @MSeifert Sorry for that, fixed :-). I really don't know, I remember finding it in the past at some point but I never giving it too much attention, maybe I'll just ask a question at some point in the future :-)

Answer (score 30):

MSeifert answer covers it broadly; to keep it simple you can think of:

**`tuple`** is immutable. Once set, you can't change it. So you know in advance how much memory you need to allocate for that object.

**`list`** is mutable. You can add or remove items to or from it. It has to know its current size. It resizes as needed.

*There are no free meals* - these capabilities comes with a cost. Hence the overhead in memory for lists.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the tuple is prefixed, i.e. at tuple initialization the interpreter allocates enough space for the contained data and hence it's immutable (can't be modified). Whereas a list is a mutable object, hence implying dynamic allocation of memory, so to avoid allocating space each time you append or modify the list (allocate enough space to contain the changed data and copy the data to it), it allocates additional space for future runtime changes, like appends and modifications.

That pretty much sums it up.