# Python: converting multi-dimensional numpy arrays into list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Suppose I have 2D `array`, for simplicity, `a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`. I want to convert it to `list` of arrays, so that the result would be:

`b=[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])]`

I found out that there is `np.ndarray.tolist()` function, but it converts N-D array into nested `list`. I could have done in a `for` loop (using `append` method), but it is not efficient/elegant.

In my real example I am working with 2D arrays of approximately 10000 x 50 elements and I want `list` that contains 50 one dimensional arrays, each of the shape `(10000,)`.

Comment: To iterate on the 2nd dimension, you may want to transpose the array first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `list`:

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = list(a)
```

Comment: Wow. This is the shortest possible solution I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use list comprehension as follows without using any `append`:

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = [i for i in a]
print (b)
```

**Output**

```
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

Comment: `[i for i in a]` is a verbose way of sayin `list(a)`

Comment: Hmm you are right. But I guess in terms of timings, they shouldn't be different. Under the hood runs the same things IMO

Comment: about the same, but no they do not. `list` will be faster.

Comment: That's the beauty of SO. You get to know different and more efficient approaches. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018398/list-uses-more-memory-than-list-comprehension) for some gory details

Comment: Thanks a lot for the interesting link. It seems the time difference becomes noticeable once the size crosses the order of 10**5.