# Reading the output of Pythons memory_profiler

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-profiling

I have a problem with understanding the `memory_profiler`s output. Basically, it looks like this:

```
Filename: tspviz.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     7  34.589844 MiB  34.589844 MiB   @profile(precision=6)
     8                             def parse_arguments():
     9  34.917969 MiB   0.328125 MiB       a = [x**2 for x in range(10000)]
```

On the 9th line we can clearly see, that we use some memory. Now, I measured the size of this list with `sys.getsizeof()`. And I double checked if it is in fact a list of ints:

```
print(sys.getsizeof(a))
print(type(a[0]))
```

And this is what I got:

```
87624
<class 'int'>
```

Well, now there's a problem. As I was checking, f.e the int in Python is of size `28` on my 64-bit Windows machine. I don't know if that's correct. But even so. `10000 * 28` = 0.28 MB. And `0.28 MB = 0.267028809 MiB` (the output from the `memory_profiler` is displaying MiB). Now the problem is, that in the table there is `0.328125 MiB`, so the difference is `0.061096191` MB.

My concern here is, well, is it really that big amount of memory needed to construct a list in Python, or am I interpreting something in a wrong way?

And P.S: Why, when this `a` list was of length `1000000`, the number in the `Increment` column for this line, when I was creating it, was like -9xxx MiB? I mean why the negative number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python lists don't store the objects themselves, but rather references to objects. The 64-bit version of Python uses 8 bytes per reference, thus `10000` ints requires `80000` bytes. From your example, `sys.getsizeof(a)` returned `87624` because for efficiency, lists allocate extra space proportional to their size. [See this post for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7247542/9909902).

The space taken by an `int` varies depending on how large it is, but `int`s up to `2^30-1` do seem to take 28 bytes on 64-bit Python (except `0`, which takes only 24 bytes). So in total, the size taken by the list is `87624 + 279996 = 367620` bytes, which is about `0.35 MiB`.

The discrepancy between this and the output from `memory_profiler` is probably due to [this](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler#frequently-asked-questions):

> This module gets the memory consumption by querying the operating
>   system kernel about the amount of memory the current process has
>   allocated, which might be slightly different from the amount of memory
>   that is actually used by the Python interpreter. Also, because of how
>   the garbage collector works in Python the result might be different
>   between platforms and even between runs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And by the way whats the `27999` in your sum?

Comment: `279996` bytes is the space taken by the actual `int`s (`10000*28-4`, since 0 takes only 24 bytes). You can verify this with `sum(sys.getsizeof(x) for x in a)`, which returns `279996`.