# How to decrease default size of memory provided by python to a variable?

Tags: python

```
List = [1,2,3]
print(sys.getsizeof(List))

Output : 96
```

That's a lot of space!!!

I am working on a problem-solving program and my only requirement is having a list that will store multiple `int` whose value will be 0 to 100.

As per my knowledge, this range's `int` can be stored by 8 bit. So total size would be `len(list) * 8`

So, in python is this possible to do something like this?

Comment: no, at least not to my knowledge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of list in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247298/size-of-list-in-memory)

Comment: Use `numpy`, it allows you to choose a byte type and minimizes the overhead.

Comment: The size of a list has ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to do with the size of the elements of the list - all it actually stores is references to the elements, which will be a 32- or 64-bit pointer depending on your platform's bit size.

Comment: Python != C. *everything* is an object. Variables reference objects, and don't have a size.

Comment: @jasonharper Yeah, but my question was about decreasing each `int` size in the list not size of reference pointer to that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns **bytes**, not bits. So you would be looking for 3. However, that's not possible, since all Python objects have **overhead**. As well, lists doesn't actually *contain* their elements, but **pointers** to them. Then I'm sure there are a lot of implementation details that further complicate things, but I'm not really qualified to talk about them.

That said, you can get closer with [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), which actually does contain its elements.

```
import array
import sys

L = [1, 2, 3]
print(sys.getsizeof(L))  # -> 80

a = array.array('B', L)  # "B" stands for "byte", AKA "unsigned char" in C
print(sys.getsizeof(a))  # -> 67
```

At this scale, the difference is marginal, but with as little as 256 elements, it's an order of magnitude.

```
L = list(range(0x100))
print(sys.getsizeof(L))  # -> 2104

a = array.array('B', L)
print(sys.getsizeof(a))  # -> 320
```

---

For more advanced uses, look into NumPy's [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

```
import numpy as np

nda = np.array(L, dtype='uint8')
print(sys.getsizeof(nda))  # -> 352
```

---

You could also consider using a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects), though semantically it makes less sense since you're trying to store numbers as bytes, not the bytes themselves. Look at the repr below to see what I mean.

```
ba = bytearray(L)
print(sys.getsizeof(ba))  # -> 342
print(ba[:11])  # -> bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n')
```

Comment: Does that have an advantage over `bytearray`?

Comment: @superb Well, I guess semantically it makes more sense. We're storing numbers as bytes, not the bytes themselves. As well, `bytearray` doesn't support signed ints, which I'm using here, although that's not really important or relevant to the question.