# Why does appending one element to an empty list occupy more memory than creating a list with one element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory-management

I'm trying to understand how the memory allocation works in Python. I've taken two lists here, I'm assigning one element to both in different ways. Assignment is done using:

1. Using the assignment operator in `list1`
2. Using the `append` method in `list2`

Before assignment both lists occupy the exact same memory, but memory allocation differs after the assignment is done in different ways. Look at the code below:

```
from sys import getsizeof as size

list1 = []
list2 = []

print(f"Memory reserved by list1 before assignment: {size(list1)}")
print(f"Memory reserved by list2 before assignment: {size(list2)}")

list1 = [8]
list2.append(8)

print(f"Memory reserved by list1 after assignment: {size(list1)}")
print(f"Memory reserved by list2 after assignment: {size(list2)}")
```

Output:

```
Memory reserved by list1 before assignment: 56
Memory reserved by list2 before assignment: 56
Memory reserved by list1 after assignment: 64
Memory reserved by list2 after assignment: 88
```

Both lists have **only one element**, still the memory allocation differs based on the assignment. How?

Comment: `list1` creates a new list, whereas `list2` is the original list which has been appended and therefore the append "costs more" to create....

Comment: Note that `list1 = [8]` does not change the original `list1` in any way, it just creates a new one and discards the original. But this is not the explanation for why they are different in size at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of a Python list in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247298/size-of-a-python-list-in-memory)