# In which algorithms or circumstances is linked list the only option?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

According to what Bjarne Stroustrup [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170566/bjarne-stroustrup-says-we-must-avoid-linked-lists), we must avoid using linked list due to several reasons. No matter how bad linked list is such as cache miss and prefetching issues, in which **algorithms** or circumstances is linked list the only option or at least much easier to fit the *real* case?

Comment: Java-targeted thread, but a lot of this applies in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: @Thilo The thread does not give any possible algorithms that linked list is preferred than other data structures.

Comment: Here is another related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496251/what-is-the-advantage-of-linked-list-over-an-array-and-vice-versa

Comment: I believe there are always *several* options when choosing a data structure, not just one. It is mostly about knowing each data structure's specific performance characteristics, then choosing an option that suits your situation. That being said, I haven't myself used (doubly) linked lists for maybe more than 15 years. I've found better data structures in pretty much every single situation.

Comment: I've always used [doubly connected edge lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) for planar graph algorithms. Not sure if that counts as a linked list and there probably are alternative data structures to represent this, but it would still be my first choice.

Answer (score 0):

- I imagine any kind of lazy list (the tail of which gets evaluated on demand) can only be done as a linked list (unless you already happen to know the length in advance).
- A (singly-) linked list can be cyclic (completely or at the "tail").
- Multiple (singly-) linked list can share memory for their tails.

Comment: Is there a reason why this answer was downvoted without even a comment?