# Does time complexity of dijkstra's algorithm for shortest path depends on data structure used?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

One way to store the graph is to implement nodes as structures, like

```
struct node {
int vertex; node* next; 
};
```

where vertex stores the vertex number and next contains link to the other node.

Another way I can think of is to implement it as vectors, like

```
vector<vector< pair<int,int> > G;
```

Now, while applying Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest path, we need to build priority queue and other required data structures and so as in case 2 (vector implementation). 
Will there be any difference in complexity in above two different methods of applying graph? Which one is preferable?

EDIT:
In first case, every node is associated with a linked list of nodes which are directly accessible from the given node. In second case,
G.size() is the number of vertices in our graph
G[i].size() is the number of vertices directly reachable from vertex with index i
G[i][j].first is the index of j-th vertex reachable from vertex i
G[i][j].second is the length of the edge heading from vertex i to vertex G[i][j].first

Comment: In a sense it does, when the original complexity analysis assumes something being O(1) (e.g. access into an array) and you replace that by something that has a worse complexity, then that will affect the overall complexity (in most cases).

Comment: For the first representation, am I correct in saying you're talking about a linked-list per vertex (which can, without much loss of generality, be simplified to `vector<list<int> >`)? For the second, will every pair in `G[x]` contain `x` (otherwise you'll need to elaborate)?

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, you are right. I mean that only.

Answer (score 1):

Both are [adjacency list representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). If implemented correctly, that would be expected to result in the same time complexity. You'd get a different time complexity if you use an [adjacency matrix representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

In more detail - this comes down to [the difference between an array (`vector`) and a linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166884/array-vs-linked-list). When all you're doing is iterating through the entire collection (i.e. the neighbours of a vertex), as you do in Dijkstra's algorithm, this takes linear time (`O(n)`) regardless of whether you're using an array or linked-list.

The resulting complexity for running Dijkstra's algorithm, as noted on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), would be
`O(|E| log |V|)` with a binary heap in either case.