# Array and Linked-list which is best in performance (in terms of access speed)

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I am studying the concepts of array and linked list ,

Which is speed in terms of accessing and why ?

Can anyone clarify this ?

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Do you really think that no-one has **ever** asked this question on Stack Overflow? Or on the entire Internet? Couldn't you **google** this? The amount of laziness you presented this question with is just mind-blowing.

Comment: My personal favorite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807759/arrays-or-linked-list-for-frequently-random-access/23809362#23809362

Answer (score 1):

The array is faster than the linked list.

Finding the n<sup>th</sup> element of an array is **O(1)**; just start at the beginning and perform one operation in pointer arithmetic. Finding the millionth element takes exactly as long as finding the tenth.

In a linked list it's **O(n)**: you must start at the beginning and step from node to node until you reach the one you want. So finding the millionth element takes 100,000 times longer than finding the tenth.