# diffrence between using list<type> and pointers (classic C) for linked lists

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

What is the pros/cons of using the built-in `std::list` instead of an own linked list implementation based on pointers like in C?

Are there some special case where one is preferred over the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166884/array-versus-linked-list

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you know there's a good reason to make your own linked list and you're willing to take on the extra work, then go for  the diy pointer linked list, otherwise stick with std::list.

Comment: @DenisBlank: that's not the same question.

Comment: my question isnt "vector (array) vs list (linked list) "

Comment: Ah ok, i understood your question wrong then.

Comment: I think the parts between parentheses in your question already point out the differences: *"(easier to deal with?)"*

Comment: stefaanv used to work with pointer in C but never deal with classes linked list using pointers. i think the class list in c++ looks easy for  use

Comment: When C-style code beats C++, it's usually because of more stack usage. For example, C-style strings and arrays can be placed on the stack. You can get around this to some extent in C++ using custom allocators. In the case of a linked list, both C and C++ approaches use dynamic memory, so there isn't much of a performance difference between the two.

Comment: @Neil Kirk clear enoght thanks

Comment: If your algorithm is dependent on a lot of splicing, having a list that don't keep track of its size might be a performance improvement. But you probably still shouldn't roll your own, there are plenty out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of good reasons to use `std::list` instead of your own linked list implementation:

1. `std::list` is guaranteed (via the c++ standard library's
   implementation of standard) to work as explained on the tin (no
   bugs, exception safety and thread safety as by the standard).
2. `std::list` does not require you to spent time developing and
   testing it.
3. `std::list` is well known so that anybody else every working with
   the code (or yourself later in life) can understand what's going on
   without the need to first get to grips with a custom linked list
   implementation.

I cannot really think of any good reason to use your own custom linked list.

`std::list` is usually implemented as a  doubly-linked list. If you only need a singly-linked list, you should consider `std::forward_list`.

Finally, if you're concerned with performance, you shouldn't use linked lists at all. Elements in a linked list are necessarily allocated individually (and often inserted at random places), so that processing a linked list generally results in many cache misses, each giving a performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you want to use `std::list`, as answered by @Walter.

However, a list implemented by "intrusively" integrating the next (and prev, if any) pointer directly into the contained objects, can avoid several disadvantages of `std::list` and the other STL containers, which may or may not be relevant to you (quoted from [Boost.Intrusive documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html#intrusive.intrusive_vs_nontrusive.properties_of_intrusive)):

> - An object can only belong to one container: If you want to share an object 
>     between two containers, you either have to store multiple copies of those 
>     objects or you need to use containers of pointers: `std::list<Object*>`.
> - The use of dynamic allocation to create copies of passed values can be a 
>     performance and size bottleneck in some applications. […]
> - Only copies of objects are stored in non-intrusive containers. Hence copy 
>     or move constructors and copy or move assignment operators are required. 
>      Non-copyable and non-movable objects can't be stored in non-intrusive 
>      containers.
> - It's not possible to store a derived object in a STL-container while 
>     retaining its original type.

The second point is probably not applicable for most typical usages of lists, where you would dynamically allocate the elements anyway.

If the last point is relevant to you, you may be interested in [Boost.PointerContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) ‒ although a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Obj>>` usually also does the job well enough.

Instead of completely implementing a list yourself, have a look at the aforementioned Boost.Intrusive library.

Comment: How are these points relevant here? Which application problems cannot be solved by using `std::container<std::shared_ptr<>>` or `std::container<std::unique_ptr<>>`? (note that, unlike `std::unique_ptr<base>`, `std::shared_ptr<base>` does not require virtual destructors: it knows the correct derived type to delete, which appears to contradict your last point)

Comment: I think that Boost.Intrusive offers advanced methods that are not only well beyond the level of the OP, but also only useful in special situations when their advantages outweight their considerable disadvantages (including being non-standard). The advice to give to the OP here is: *use the standard library*. Only if you know the standard library well and your requirements cannot be satisfied by it, should you ever consider things like Boost.Intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Walter covers the main reasons to prefer the stl implementation. The main reason to consider a clasic C style implementation is increased performance. The cost of this increased performance is primarily the potential for errors. This can be addressed with testing and the inclusion of some appropriate asserts (checks for null pointers..._

Contrary to the statements in Walter's answer there are cases where a high performance list is a good data structure choice.

If you need the performance of a custom list but want to avoid the work of constructing and testing your own check out the boost intrusive lists (singly and doubly linked) at:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/intrusive.html
These will get you the same performance as a custom construction with (almost) the convenience of the stl versions.

Comment: This seems like an informative answer. Would the downvoter care to comment on how the answer could be improved?

Comment: It does not compare using `std::list` with a C-style pointer implementation.

Comment: It does not answer the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza i confirm nothing to do with the question